# Does Image Mosaic need a rast mapping

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

geoserver.log gives the following warning a bunch of times when loading my Image Mosaic layers

```
WARN [geotools.jdbc] - Could not find mapping for 'rast', ignoring the column and setting the feature type read only
```

I'm not using ImageMosaic JDBC, but I am using Image Mosaic with the time dimension attribute which generates a POSTGIS table pointing to the locations of the .tif files

```
fid, the_geom, location, ingestion
1,  010300...,  arnoldred_bloom_prism_2001.tif, 2000-12-31 17:00:00.000000
```

Do I need to add a rast mapping since the raster is not actually stored in the database. If not is there a way to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: This warning looks unrelated to the imagemosaic index.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @simogeo I think you are right in that the warning isn't image mosaic specific. Is it just a warning for anytime you store a raster outdb stating that you can't write to the raster? If that's the case is there anyway to suppress the warning as they flood the log.

Comment: I think it would need some changes into the code, as the log level is WARN.

You might want to do it yourself or open a JIRA report for it.